# "Anonymous" Youtube Playlists

Tags: html, youtube-api

Is there a way to embed a playlist of youtube videos in HTML by listing the youtube videos in the embed code, rather than defining a playlist in my youtube account?

Comment: @whoever voted to close - Actually, this is a web development question. It has to do with youtube's player api. I'm wondering about a feature that I feel is likely there, but can't find any documentation on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find that this isn't possible with the YouTube API (I may be incorrect here), but I have been unable to find anything of the sort on the internet.

Also, everything I found which related to YouTube play-list embedding required you to login beforehand.

**Update:**

I found this: http://www.php-help.ro/mootools-12-javascript-examples/youtube-player-embed-with-attached-playlist/

Which uses MooTools to grab a playlist for a certain user.

Hope that helps!

And the demo: http://php-help.ro/examples/youtube_player_mootools/

Answer (score 6):

This is quit simple
Just use the embed code (iframe or object code) and a parameter to the url
After playlist= you add the youtube id's comma seperated
Here an example

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/uG53Ce5_dI0?version=3&playlist=YW8p8JO2hQw,UouwabEZy2E,IXJ9uiT4nEM,bRcdlZ87GVY,IA96yoK9l7M,ZEU4rugs-74
```

Comment: Does [this URL](http://www.youtube.com/v/uG53Ce5_dI0?version=3&playlist=YW8p8JO2hQw,UouwabEZy2E,IXJ9uiT4nEM,bRcdlZ87GVY,IA96yoK9l7M,ZEU4rugs-74) still work? I followed the link, but it doesn't show a playlist.